# Can I make a command to be the col-offset always 1 on every screen sizes in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, offset

Let's assume I want to make an element which has equivalent offset all on the screen sizes. I only saw examples where people concretely adjusted the size like:
col-offset-md-2

What if I want to do something like this?

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-offset-xs-1 col-offset-md-1 etc...">
```

As you can see it's not a nice solution, the lines are growing too big. Can I make a command to be the offset always 1 on every screen sizes? Something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-offset-1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `col-xs-offset-1` to offset all column size by one.

Note: The way you are writing the column offset `col-offset-xs-1` is not correct either.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:#A9A9A9;">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color:#6495ED;">
   Offset Every Column By 1
  </div>
</div>
```